# Stationary distribution of AR(1) process with AR(1) shocks

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity, autoregressive

I am trying to find the stationary distribution of an AR(1) process, where the shock terms themselves are an AR(1) process. That is, the process moves subject to the following 2 equations:
\begin{equation}
    z_{t+1} = \rho z_t + \sigma_t \eta_{z,t+1} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sigma^2_{t+1} = \max\left\{\nu \sigma_t^2  + \sigma \eta_{\sigma,t+1},\: 0 \right\}
\end{equation}
where $\eta_{\sigma, t+1}, \eta_{z,t+1} \sim N(0,1)$ are IID.

I believe that the stationary distribution of $\sigma_t \eta_{z,t+1}$ is a linear combination of $\chi$-square distributions. (Based on answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian))

Does this mean that the stationary distribution of $z_{t+1}$ is also the same linear combination of $\chi$-square distributions?

Comment: This looks more like some kind of stochastic volatility shocks rather than AR(1) shocks.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to prove an existence result for the Bansal and Yaron stochastic volatility model. Does that change the nature of the problem?

Comment: I do not think altering the name changes the nature of the problem, but it changes the relevance of your title (currently a little misleading).